# Contrast matrix with two factors with more than 2 levels each

Tags: linear-model, experiment-design, contrasts

I have not come across a contrast matrix like the one I would like to make. To put it in situation. I have the following model:

```
design_matrix <- model.matrix(~ factor1*factor2, data = data)

factor1: Has 4 different levels.
factor2: Has 3 different levels.
response: single cell log normalized count data
```

My data dimensions are `20000 genes and 30000 cells.`

This leads to a total of 12 coefficients including the intercept. My reference level would be **`factor1_level1 and factor2_level1`**. Here are the coefficients:

```
> colnames(design_matrix)
 [1] "(Intercept)"                 "factor1_level2"           "factor1_level3"           "factor1_level4"         
 [5] "factor2_level2"                      "factor2_level3"                    "factor1_level2:factor2_level2"    "factor1_level3:factor2_level2"   
 [9] "factor1_level4:factor2_level2"   "factor1_level2:factor2_level3"  "factor1_level3:factor2_level3"  "factor1_level4:factor2_level3"
```

I want to see which genes are differentially expressed comparing each level within factor1 for each level in factor2. For example this would be the case for factor2_level1:

```
Differences between factor1_level1 and the rest(factor1_level2 , factor1_level3 , factor1_level4) for factor2_level1
Differences between factor1_level2 and the rest(factor1_level1 , factor1_level3 , factor1_level4) for factor2_level1
Differences between factor1_level3 and the rest(factor1_level1 , factor1_level2 , factor1_level4) for factor2_level1
Differences between factor1_level4 and the rest(factor1_level1 , factor1_level2 , factor1_level3) for factor2_level1
```

Then the idea would be to do the same contrasts but for `factor2_level2 and factor2_level3`

I estimate my coefficients using a linear model:

```
lmfit <- lmFit(data, design_matrix)
```

Then I would like to apply the contrasts I stated above. In total they should be 12 comparisons (`4 levels in factor1 * 3 levels in factor2`).

Then I would like to apply the contrasts I stated above. In total they should be 12 comparisons (`4 levels in factor1 * 3 levels in factor2`). For instance could this be correct?

```
Example1: Differences between factor1_level2 and the rest(factor1_level1 , factor1_level3 , factor1_level4) for factor2_level2
```

Given the coefficients as I stated above:

```
K <- matrix(c(0, 1, -1/2,-1/2, 1, 0, 1,-1/2,-1/2,0,0,0), 1)
```

Another example:

```
Differences between factor1_level1 and the rest(factor1_level2 , factor1_level3 , factor1_level4) for factor2_level1

K <- matrix(c(1, -1/3,-1/3,-1/3, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0), 1)
```

I would appreciate some insight about this contrasts!

Thanks in advance!